# How to fix phantom "Failed to estimate balance changes. This transaction may be unsafe"

Tags: phantom, transaction

I have an issue where I create a transaction on the backend and pay for the transaction fees, then I serialize and send the transaction to the frontend for the user to sign. It works however I get this Prompt from phantom always and it takes a long time after clicking confirm - but the transaction goes through.

How do you properly make a transaction such that it is safe and able to show the balance changes? should be 0 here since the transaction/rent fees are already paid for by a backend wallet.

Thanks!

Here is the transaction:

```
{
    "recentBlockhash": "BqTPpSb74yPSikcVy1p3e5BmyGpDqY8cbmN7g4D2pUvd",
    "feePayer": "L8WnqU2xmTxyQdeNdMDJonBEueBcMyfH33zJgsx9xz9",
    "nonceInfo": null,
    "instructions": [
        {
            "keys": [
                {
                    "pubkey": "4oLzhJMmhiiVWi6H42WmkeTaHn6kfAMEezY5BCZpeFCu",
                    "isSigner": false,
                    "isWritable": true
                },
                {
                    "pubkey": "B5nXXypvm4xeGtAUAPepYLfJV5PsfKvZj4c7SGD3ri53",
                    "isSigner": false,
                    "isWritable": true
                },
                {
                    "pubkey": "2za7tzXbWeJiRhCiaWbdZbxUKpawjWgNpzksptiSguZF",
                    "isSigner": false,
                    "isWritable": true
                },
                {
                    "pubkey": "E5CdwMifQH9CeHGjNf8YefDb6EDqJK84zuVNqGHks8tR",
                    "isSigner": false,
                    "isWritable": false
                },
                {
                    "pubkey": "6xZ4UjShw6qfoR15BxyMfbukWcHN4nVFvCNDQNscggXM",
                    "isSigner": false,
                    "isWritable": true
                },
                {
                    "pubkey": "FgwM9n3damZc4CG8VZU9tTrJ7nWLA6T51URNZ2fnh7Gm",
                    "isSigner": false,
                    "isWritable": false
                },
                {
                    "pubkey": "L8WnqU2xmTxyQdeNdMDJonBEueBcMyfH33zJgsx9xz9",
                    "isSigner": true,
                    "isWritable": true
                },
                {
                    "pubkey": "a7PQyMNYxikUT5jAxeLhSz5c1PWMZEDqXBW9HbSnE4x",
                    "isSigner": true,
                    "isWritable": false
                },
                {
                    "pubkey": "ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL",
                    "isSigner": false,
                    "isWritable": false
                },
                {
                    "pubkey": "TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA",
                    "isSigner": false,
                    "isWritable": false
                },
                {
                    "pubkey": "11111111111111111111111111111111",
                    "isSigner": false,
                    "isWritable": false
                }
            ],
            "programId": "B2ejsK7m3eYPerru92hS73Gx7sQ7J83DKoLHGwn6pg5v",
            "data": [
                42,
                192,
                142,
                50,
                73,
                168,
                119,
                96,
                1,
                0,
                0,
                0,
                0,
                0,
                0,
                0
            ]
        }
    ],
    "signers": [
        "L8WnqU2xmTxyQdeNdMDJonBEueBcMyfH33zJgsx9xz9",
        "a7PQyMNYxikUT5jAxeLhSz5c1PWMZEDqXBW9HbSnE4x"
    ]
}
```

[image]

Comment: It might be best to ask Phantom directly and find out their criteria